# Flip toggle switch does not append in listview in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new in jQuery mobile, all li append in ul perfectly but only `data-role=slider` do not append.

```
function getWebsiteDirectries() 
{
var customer = "";
var li = "";
if(user_id.length != 0){
    url = serviceURL +'customer-info.json?id='+user_id+'&action=get&request_type=web_directory';
    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {  
       $('#web_list li').remove();  
        customer = json.items;            
        $.each(customer, function(key, value) {                         

             $.each(value.customer.customer_toplist, function(key, value) {

                    li += '<li style="height:40px; line-height:40px;"><span class="f_right"><select data-role="slider" id="'+value.vName+'" name="'+value.vName+'" class="ui-slider-switch"><option value="0">OFF</option><option value="1">ON</option></select></span>'+value.vTitle+'</li>';

            });             
            $('#web_list').append(li);  
            $('#web_list').listview('refresh');                     
        });

    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add :

```
$('#web_list').trigger('create');
```

between this:

```
$('#web_list').append(li);  
$('#web_list').trigger('create');
$('#web_list').listview('refresh');
```